# Combining nested and multiple views for a single state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ok so I am trying to combine both nested and multiple views with angular-ui-router.

I have the following HTML:

**Index.html**

```
<div ui-view="viewA"></div>
```

**viewA.html**

```
index.viewA

<div ui-view="viewANested"></div>
```

**viewANested.html**

```
index.viewA.nested
```

And the following javascript:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "viewA.html",
                views: {
                  "viewANested":{
                    templateUrl: "viewANested.html"
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
```

A plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7vvKws?p=preview), I am trying to combine both multiple and nested views but it isn't working for me. I can see the outer view just fine but no joy in the inner one, with no errors in the console.

For the sake of simplicity I have removed the multiple views from the example, but the HTML/Javascript wouldn't change in structure if they were there.

I have tried this javascript also:

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "viewA.html",
            }
            "viewANested": {
                templateUrl: "viewANested.html",
            }
        }
    });
})
```

This isn't working either (combined with changing the **ui-view** property to 'viewA.Nested'):

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "",
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                templateUrl: "viewA.html"
            },
            "viewA.Nested":{
              templateUrl: "viewANested.html"
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Still no joy, I can't think of any other way to do this, can somebody shed some light on where I am going wrong?

Am I making a mistake or is this a limitation of the framework itself?

I think the alternative is to have a flatter structure, and extra mostly unused divs on my index page that I can use if neccessary to put content into for more complex pages, is that the way to go? It seems a bit hacky.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the example demo/plnkr here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22189954/1803298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. With `ui-router` we can have many/nested views defined for one state. The updated [plunker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rGmjF4?p=preview). I've used your last attempt, and this is the only change I made:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "",
        views: {
        "viewA": {
            templateUrl: "viewA.html"
          },
          // "viewA.Nested":{
          "viewANested@index":{
            templateUrl: "viewANested.html"
          }
        }
    });
```

As we can see, instead of name **`"viewA.Nested"`** I used this: **`"viewANested@index"`**

The most important part is the delimiter **`@`** followed by state name **`index`** - which is the target where is the view name **`viewANested`** searched for.

See the doc and more here:

- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

Comment: Does this work further down the nesting? Is *`viewANested@index.detail`* valid? I'm trying to work out if that is my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28749378/1075247).

Comment: I have the same problem as @Pureferret . Let's say viewANested has another view inside it, how can we put it?