# Doubly-nested views in UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Playing around with angular-ui and specifically using the `ui-router` module to do some nested views. I'm having trouble getting a partial to render within a partial:

The nesting is as follows:

```
index.html
    -main.form.html
    -main.sidebar.html
        -sidebar.slider.html
```

My current `app.js` setup is:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'sidebar': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/main.sidebar.html',
                    views: {
                        'slider': {
                            templateUrl: 'views/partials/sidebar.slider.html'
                        }

                    }

                },
                'form': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/main.form.html',

                },
                'tribute': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/main.tribute.html',
                },
                'submit': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/partials/submit.html',
                }
            }
        })
```

All other partials load and I can see the `ui-view` directive loading in the browser, but the actual partial isn't rendered (the div just contains the `ui-view="sidebar.slider"` literal)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view nesting, inside of one state, is done via their [relative/absolute](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) view name *(not via object nesting)*

Let's say, that the `templateUrl` contains the `ui-view="slider"`, then we have to target that *view* name absolutely

```
$stateProvider
   .state('main', {
     url: '/',
     views: {
      'sidebar': {
         templateUrl: 'views/partials/main.sidebar.html',
       },
      // this view definition is on the same level
      // but the absolute name says, that it should be searched
      // inside of the 'main' state
      'slider@main': {
         templateUrl: 'views/partials/sidebar.slider.html'
      },
      ...
```

the key here is the name of the view 'slider@main', which contains from view name 'slider' delimiter '@' and the state name 'main'. Check these for more details:

- [Combining nested and multiple views for a single state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616367/)
- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

Comment: Awesome; thanks! I especially appreciate the delineation between absolute and object nesting. Thanks!