# UI router - Multiple nested named views in a single state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
index.html
--navbar.html
--content.html
  --customer.html
    --netScore.html
    --useExp.html
      --useExpNest1.html
      --useExpNest2.html
  --internalPerformance.html
--leftNavPanel.html
```

I have this kind of view structure and I want to load them all at once so I'm planning to put this in a single state. I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638677/doubly-nested-views-in-ui-router) but it seems that its only applicable for a simple/double nested views(I have 3 or more nested views). How can I put this in a single state, or is there a better way if not possible?

**EDIT**

I've come up with this solution and it works somehow.

```
.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index.view.html',
            controller: 'indexController'
        },
        'navbar@index': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index/navbar.view.html',
            controller: 'navbarController'
        },
        'content@index': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index/content.view.html',
            controller: 'contentController'
        },
        'leftNavPanel@index': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index/leftNavPanel.view.html',
            controller: 'contentController'
        }
    }
})
.state('index.content', {
    views: {
        'customer@index': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index/content/customer.view.html'
        },
        'internalPerformance@index': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index/content/internalPerformance.view.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('index.content.customer', {
    views: {
        'netScore@index.content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index/content/customer/netScore.view.html'
        },
        'useExp@index.content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index/content/customer/useExp.view.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('index.content.customer.useExp', {
    views: {
        'useExpNest1@index.content.customer': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index/content/customer/useExp/useExpNest1.view.html'
        },
        'useExpNest2@index.content.customer': {
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/bulletin/views/index/content/customer/useExp/useExpNest2.view.html'
        }
    }
})
```

And then add this code to the indexController(most parent controller)

```
$state.go('index.content');
$state.go('index.content.customer');
$state.go('index.content.customer.useExp');
```

But this answer is still wrong because, let's say that **netScore.html** has some child views, we will create route for it then go to that state, but **netScore** and **useExp** states are on the same level so only one of them will be loaded if we use

```
$state.go('index.content');
$state.go('index.content.customer');
$state.go('index.content.customer.netScore');
$state.go('index.content.customer.useExp');
```

**EDIT 2**
Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l6f8HF2ut39DtMoBJFYI?p=preview) of what I've done so far. The view names are slightly different but you will see clearly the problem there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the guys from AngularJS group in FB. The problem is I put two sibling views in two different states. UI router cant load two states at the same time. So the solution is to put all same level views in a single subState.

Lets assume we have this kind of structure:

```
index.html
--navbar.html
--content.html
  --customer.html
    --netScore.html
      --netScoreNest1.html
      --netScoreNest2.html
    --useExp.html
      --useExpNest1.html
      --useExpNest2.html
  --internalPerformance.html
--leftNavPanel.html
```

the proper routing for this would be like this

```
.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'index.view.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        },
        'navbar@main': {
            templateUrl: 'index/navbar.view.html'
        },
        'content@main': {
            templateUrl: 'index/content.view.html'
        },
        'leftNavPanel@main': {
            templateUrl: 'index/leftNavPanel.view.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('index.subLevel', {
    views: {
        'customer@index': {
            templateUrl: 'index/content/customer.view.html'
        },
        'internalPerformance@index': {
            templateUrl: 'index/content/internalPerformance.view.html'
        }
        // IF LEFTNAVPANEL OR NAVBAR HAVE SUB VIEWS, PUT IT HERE
    }
})
.state('index.subLevel.subLevel2', {
    views: {
        'netScore@index.subLevel': {
            templateUrl: 'index/content/customer/netScore.view.html'
        },
        'useExp@index.subLevel': {
            templateUrl: 'index/content/customer/useExp.view.html'
        }
        // IF INTERNALPERFORMANCE HAVE SUB VIEWS, PUT IT HERE
    }
})
.state('index.subLevel.subLevel2.subLevel3', {
    views: {
        'netScoreNest1@index.subLevel.subLevel2': {
            templateUrl: 'index/content/customer/netScore/netScoreNest1.view.html'
        },
        'netScoreNest2@index.subLevel.subLevel2': {
            templateUrl: 'index/content/customer/netScore/netScoreNest2.view.html'
        },
        'useExpNest1@index.subLevel.subLevel2': {
            templateUrl: 'index/content/customer/useExp/useExpNest1.view.html'
        },
        'useExpNest2@index.subLevel.subLevel2': {
            templateUrl: 'index/content/customer/useExp/useExpNest2.view.html'
        }
    }
})
```

And then in mainController, load the inner most child state, this will automatically load the views of all its parent(up to topmost parent state 'index')

```
$state.go('index.subLevel.subLevel2.subLevel3');
```

And thats it. And also here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l6f8HF2ut39DtMoBJFYI?p=preview) to make it easier to understand. (Views and structure are slightly different from this post different. Too lazy to edit)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of named views plus abstract: true property to load child views by default

```
angular.module('sampleModule', [
  'ui.router'  
]);


angular.module('sampleModule')
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('','/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'main.view.html'
        })
        .state('main.load', {
            url: '/',
            abstract: true,
            views:{
              'content':{
                templateUrl:'content.view.html',
              },
              'navbar':{
                templateUrl:'navbar.view.html',
              }
            }
        })
        .state('main.load.customer', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            views:{
              'customerPerception':{
                templateUrl:'content-customerPerception.view.html'
              },
              'customerExperience':{
                templateUrl:'content-customerExperience.view.html'
              }
            }
        })
        .state('main.load.customer.netTrustScore', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'netTrustScore': {
                    templateUrl: 'content-customerPerception-netTrustScore.view.html'
                },
                'useExperience': {
                    templateUrl: 'content-customerPerception-useExperience.view.html'
                },
                'trustStatements': {
                    templateUrl: 'content-customerPerception-trustStatements.view.html'
                }
            }
        })
    .state('main.load.customer.netTrustScore.somethingElse', {
            url: '',
            views: {
                'abc': {
                    templateUrl: 'content-customerExperience-customerComplaints.view.html'
                },
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'content-customerExperience-networkQualityIndex.view.html'
        }
            }
        })
    ;
}])

.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {

    console.log('mainController initialized!');


}]);
```

here's a plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/BBAeWjnGbTsbO1lMguU9?p=preview

Comment: I have 2 views on the same level(customerPerception and customerExperience) that have children. Using this solution will only load one of them.