# ng-view inside the another ng-view possible

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view

> Nested ng-view is possible in angularjs or if any alternative solution
>   for this one. If it is possible for ng-view inside the ng-view.

Comment: look at `ui-router`, and use nested `ui-view`.

Comment: @MattWay ui-view is like ng-view

Comment: As @MattWay says ui-router's nested states is what you're after.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637350/nesting-ng-views-in-angular-js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187231/doubly-nested-views-ui-router-or-ui-bootstrap-tabs-accordion

Comment: @MattWay ui-router stable version is aviable for download

Answer (score 2):

use ui-router for nested views.. read about comparison between ngRoute & uiRouter [here](http://cacodaemon.de/index.php?id=57)

below is an example of how to define nested views...

```
.state('bulletinBoard', {
        url: '/bulletinBoard',
        templateUrl: '../src/app/bulletinBoard/views/bulletinBoard.part.html',
        views: {
            'tradeFeed': {
                controller: 'tradeFeedController',
                templateUrl: '../src/app/bulletinBoard/views/tradeFeed.part.html'
            },
            'newsFeed': {
                controller: 'newsFeedController',
                templateUrl: '../src/app/bulletinBoard/views/newsFeed.part.html'
            }
        }
        });
```

the best source for reading about nested view, is the official documentation [link here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)